# Use Object as Parameter with SignalR

Tags: javascript, c#, .net, signalr, signalr.client

I am trying to send an object from the client to the server and then from the server to the client(s). This is using the example code provided by Microsoft that I have slightly modified to use an object instead of a primitive, the code is below. The callback function on the client is never getting called after the `connection.send` from the JS client.

*`Hub` class*:

```
public class Chat : Hub
{
    public void BroadcastMessage(MessageModel message)
    {
        Clients.All.SendAsync("broadcastMessage", message);
    }
}
```

*Model Class*:

```
public class MessageModel
{
    [JsonProperty("to")]
    public string _to = "";

    [JsonProperty("from")]
    public string _from = "";

    [JsonProperty("message")]
    public string _message = "";

    public MessageModel(string to, string from, string message)
    {
        _to = to;
        _from = from;
        _message = message;
    }
}
```

*Client Side JS (where I think the problem is...)*:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@aspnet/signalr@1.0.0/dist/browser/signalr.min.js">

function onConnected(connection) {
            console.log('connection started');
            //connection.send('broadcastMessage', '_SYSTEM_', username + ' JOINED');

            document.getElementById('sendmessage').addEventListener('click', function (event) {
                // Call the broadcastMessage method on the hub.
                if (messageInput.value) {
                    var msgObject = { to: 'Sally', from: 'Jonny', message: 'this is message' };
                    var myJSON = JSON.stringify(msgObject);
                    console.log(myJSON);

                    //neither object or stringify work
                    connection.send('broadcastMessage', msgObject);
                }

                // Clear text box and reset focus for next comment.
                messageInput.value = '';
                messageInput.focus();
                event.preventDefault();
            });
        }

function bindConnectionMessage(connection)
        {
            var messageCallback = function (message)
            {
                console.log('Never hits here...');

                if (!message) return;

                // Html encode display name and message.
                var encodedName = message.from;
                var encodedMsg = message.message.replace(/&/g, "&amp;").replace(/</g, "&lt;").replace(/>/g, "&gt;");
                var messageEntry = createMessageEntry(encodedName, encodedMsg);
                            
                var messageBox = document.getElementById('messages');
                messageBox.appendChild(messageEntry);
                messageBox.scrollTop = messageBox.scrollHeight;
            };

            // Create a function that the hub can call to broadcast messages.
            connection.on('broadcastMessage', messageCallback);
            connection.on('echo', messageCallback);
            connection.onclose(onConnectionError);
        }
```

I've been at this for ages and can't figure out why it is so difficult.  I suspect it's something really obvious but could really use some help.  Thank you!

Comment: Open your browser's Developer Tools' Network window and inspect the WebSocket messages to see what's going on.

Comment: Which library are you using client-side?

Comment: @JoshWulf I am using the following client-side lib.
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@aspnet/signalr@1.0.0/dist/browser/signalr.min.js">

Comment: @JoshWulf I updated the JS in the question too

Comment: Hub Connection send doesn't take a callback, it returns a Promise: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/%40aspnet/signalr/hubconnection?view=signalr-js-latest#send. What documentation applies to what you are doing?

Comment: @JoshWulf here is the example project from Microsoft
https://github.com/aspnet/AzureSignalR-samples/tree/master/samples/ChatRoomLocal

Comment: @JoshWulf I can solve my problem if I pass in a JSON string into the JS and then deserialize it in the hub then reserialize and send back as JSON only to deserialize it again on the client.

Comment: Looks like you need to pass in a username - or is that optional? `connection.send('broadcastMessage', username, messageInput.value);`

Comment: Yes, you need to serialize it if the library doesn't do it as a convenience. That's standard.

Comment: @JoshWulf I modified the connection.send you referenced above (from sample project not from my code sample) to pass an object which is what this problem is regarding.  I had thought that as with libs like WebAPI the serialization etc. is handled for you with the class attributes but if no one else has any ideas on this then I guess I will have to do it all manually as I mentioned already, although this seems odd and like there should be a solution for this as there is with WebAPI.

Comment: @user2712697 the client package is now obsolete, update to ```@microsoft/signalr```.

Comment: @user2712697 and I don't see where in the client code, you have the invoke methods to your hub.

Comment: @kiril1512 I updated to the @microsoft/signalr and also updated to most recent @aspnet/signalr neither would work.  I appears there is no way that the libs handle serialization and desirialization for you.  Seems totally nuts but you must do it manually yourself it would appear.  Wish someone could prove me wrong still...

Answer (score 1):

I believe that you should user the `Invoke` method insted of `Send` like:

```js
connection.invoke('BroadcastMessage', msgObject);
```

> Note: the method name is case sensitive, so if your hub has `BroadcastMessage` on the client it should be the same and not `broadcastMessage`.

Comment: Thanks, @Kiril1512 I tried this but it didn't work.  Same results as send